# Use SAS Macro variable on a PROC SQL Teradata Connections

Tags: sas

I want to automate a connection string to Teradata on SAS without repeating it all the time using a macro as below;

```
%MACRO ODBC_Connect;
PROC SQL;
CONNECT TO TERADATA AS ODBC(UID=&ID. PWD=&PWD. SERVER=&SRVR.);
%MEND;
%MACRO ODBC_Disconnect;
DISCONNECT FROM ODBC;
QUIT;
%MEND;
```

SO that whenever i need it I can call it up and use it as below;

```
%ODBC_Connect;
CREATE TABLE OUT.TEST AS
SELECT * FROM CONNECTION TO ODBC
(
select top 10 *
from S_CAAS_XXXX.MIS_CUST
where EFF_STA_DTE<=&end_dt.
AND EFF_END_DTE>&end_dt.

 );
%ODBC_Disconnect;
```

But code brings errors

Comment: You are referencing a lot of macro variables that you have not shown us values for.  Are you saying the CONNECT statement is not working? Or the WHERE clause is not working?

Comment: You should consider keyboard macros instead if you're using Base SAS. If not, you may want to consider a libname method instead of using explicit pass through so that your connection is maintained.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of having them both separately, have a single macro and use SYSPBUFF to hold the macro parameters (i.e. the SQL string). You may run into some macro quoting issues depending on the SQL you pass into it, but this is a rough idea...

```
%MACRO ODBCSQL /parmbuff ;
  /* trim off the open/close parentheses on SYSPBUFF */
  %LET SQL = %SUBSTR(&SYSPBUFF,2,%LENGTH(&SYSPBUFF)-2)) ;
  proc sql ;
    connect to blah ;
    &SQL ;
    disconnect from blah ;
  quit ;
%MEND ;

%ODBCSQL(create table blah as ... etc etc) ;
```